# PySpark - Create Age Column Over a Window starting based on the first Non Zero Value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
    [Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2017, 12, 31), Total=0.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 1, 31), Total=4006),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 2, 28), Total=2389),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 3, 31), Total=0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 4, 30), Total=3547),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 5, 31), Total=4322)
......]
```

What I want to do is create a new column "age" based on the "Total" Column.The "age" column needs to be a row_number starting from the first non-zero value in "Total". The output needs to be:

```
[Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2017, 12, 31), Total=0.0, age = None),
Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 1, 31), Total=4006, age = 1),
Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 2, 28), Total=2389, age = 2),
Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 3, 31), Total=0 ,age = 3),
Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 4, 30), Total=3547,age = 4),
Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 5, 31), Total=4322,age = 5)]
```

I started off with this given I have many IDs in the dataframe

```
sample.\
withColumn("age",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("MONTH_END"))).take(10)
```

But this does not consider looking at the first non zero value in the Total Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the `first` aggregation that has `ignorenulls` option. Using a couple of auxiliary columns that can be dropped later:

- `rnum` the row number in the window
- `delta` which is the `rnum` of the first row with `Total != 0`

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2017, 12, 31), Total=0.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 1, 31), Total=4006.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 2, 28), Total=2389.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 3, 31), Total=0.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 4, 30), Total=3547.0),
    Row(ID=123, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 5, 31), Total=4322.0),
    Row(ID=124, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 5, 31), Total=0.0),
    Row(ID=125, MONTH_END=datetime.date(2018, 5, 31), Total=4322.0)
])

win = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("MONTH_END")
df.withColumn("rnum", row_number().over(win)) \
    .withColumn("delta", first(when(col("Total") == 0, None).otherwise(col("rnum")), ignorenulls=True).over(win))\
    .withColumn("age", when(col("delta").isNull(), None).otherwise(col("rnum")-col("delta")+1))\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
.+---+----------+------+----+-----+----+
| ID| MONTH_END| Total|rnum|delta| age|
+---+----------+------+----+-----+----+
|124|2018-05-31|   0.0|   1| null|null|
|123|2017-12-31|   0.0|   1| null|null|
|123|2018-01-31|4006.0|   2|    2|   1|
|123|2018-02-28|2389.0|   3|    2|   2|
|123|2018-03-31|   0.0|   4|    2|   3|
|123|2018-04-30|3547.0|   5|    2|   4|
|123|2018-05-31|4322.0|   6|    2|   5|
|125|2018-05-31|4322.0|   1|    1|   1|
+---+----------+------+----+-----+----+
```

Left the columns `rnum` and `delta` for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!